# error " cannot create directory /root" when using comand su username

Tags: server

I have server with multiple websites, and each website has their own user. Each time I want to do some modification to particular website I do `su username` and go to the folder for that website.

the problem is each time I do `su username` it show this error :

```
mkdir: cannot create directory `/root': Permission denied
```

this is very strange, why command `su username` want to create a folder in `/root`? is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Does /root exist already on your machine

Comment: yes , my machine has /root

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
su - username
```

I had the same problem and I took a look at the su manpage and noticed the *login* flags under options. Are you logged in as root when you do this work? If so, using su without loading the target user environment could result in this kind of error.

```
-, -l, --login 

  Provide an environment similar to what the user would expect had
  the user logged in directly.

  When - is used, it must be specified as the last su option. The
  other forms (-l and --login) do not have this restriction.
```

[Source](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/maverick/man1/su.1.html)